# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point

Tags: javascript, selenium

Exception in thread "main" **`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException`**: Element is not clickable at `point (126, 7.98333740234375)`.

Other element would receive the click: `<div class="_1H5F__" data-reactid="10"></div>`

Command duration or timeout: `162 milliseconds`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Place delay or explicit wait for that particular element before the line of code where exception is occurred. Instead of using sleep use explicit wait is good practise, because it will take same time given in sleep even after element is found. Hope it will be useful to you.

Reference: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/ie_exports_Driver.html#wait

Answer (score 0):

Generally, i used to try

1. providing waits (implicit or explicit)
2. if waits not works well then Thread.sleep in java

provided that locator is valid one.. some times i tried changing locator also..

Sometimes, movetoElement before click on that element also helps.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is an element above the one you are trying to click - that is literary what the exception says. And if that element is there to stay - a "popup", out notification overlay, no waiting will make it go away.

Check what when element is obfuscating your target, and deal with it - close if it is closable, or interact, so it does not stay on top.